# ¿Cómo pasar un directorio por teclado y borrarlo en Java?

Tags: java, archivo, entrada, teclado

Estoy empezando a programar y no se cómo puedo pasar por teclado un directorio y que lo borre.

Si pongo a mano la ruta del directorio que quiero borrar, si lo borra, pero si lo pido por teclado, me indica que el directorio no existe.

```
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Actividad1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String  directorio=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Qué directorio quieres borrar?");
        File dir=new File(directorio);
        
        if(dir.exists()) {
            File[]listaFich=dir.listFiles();
            
            System.out.println("Hay "+listaFich.length+" ficheros en este directorio.");
            
            for(int i=0;i<listaFich.length;i++) {
        
                if(listaFich[i].isFile()) {
                    
                    listaFich[i].delete();
                    System.out.println("Se ha borrado "+listaFich[i]);
                }
            }
            
            if(dir.delete()) {
                
                System.out.println("Se ha borrado el directorio '"+dir.getName()+"'");
            }else {
                
                System.out.println("No se ha podido borrar el directorio "+dir.getName());
            }
        }else {
            
            System.out.println("NO EXISTE EL DIRECTORIO.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tu código funciona. Quizá no estas copiando la ruta correctamente.

Comment: Hola Oscar! Gracias por contestar! Cuando me sale el cuadro de texto preguntándome, que directorio quiero borrar, yo meto el nombre del directorio sin mas. ¿Cómo meto la ruta que me dices?

Comment: Si tienes Windows te ubicas en la carpeta que esta tu archivo, después haz clic derecho y clic a propiedades, te saldrá una ventana y ahí hay una etiqueta que dice ubicación. Ejemplo "C:\Documents\CarpetaProyecto " . Toma en cuenta que esto borra la carpeta donde este ubicado, así que ten cuidado.

Comment: Osea que cuando me pide el directorio, tengo que meter la ruta entera. No solo el nombre del directorio. Pensaba que poniendo el  nombre del directorio ya lo encontraba el solo...Gracias de nuevo.